# jQuery if statement change div class to another not class

Tags: jquery, class, html, if-statement

Is it possible, with the use of an if-statement to change the class of one div, for example #carriage-promo, to another, for example #carriage-promo-2?

Consider:

```
if(! navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) &&
 ! navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) &&
 ! navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) &&
 ! navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) &&
 ! navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) &&
 ! navigator.userAgent.match(/Blackberry/i) )
    {
        $('#carriage-promo').css({'position':'fixed','bottom':'0px','width':'100%'});
    } else {
        $('#carriage-promo').css({'display':'inline-block', 'height':'40px'});
        alert('tablet detected');
        //change #carriage-promo to #carriage-promo-2
    }
```

Instead of changing just one property of the class, I'd like to change the entire class from one to another IF the user is browsing from one of the above devices.

Comment: $('#id') is the ID selector, class selector is $(".class") (http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not too sure if you want to change the ID or Class attribute. If it's class, then just replace id with class.

```
$('#carriage-promo').attr('id', 'carriage-promo-2');
```

Or, if it's the class that you want to change, you could do

```
$('#carriage-promo').addClass('class_name');
```

Comment: The class, not the ID - my mistake.

Thanks, I haven't tried using .attr, but I assume this changes the attributes associated with whatever is selected?

Comment: Yes, it does. And with jQuery's attr, you can change not only ID's and classes, but also href (if it's an anchor tag), src (if it's an img) and many more depending on what kind of element it is. More info here: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) to add css class and [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) to remove css class

```
  if(! navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) && ! navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) &&
     ! navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) && ! navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) &&
     ! navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) &&! navigator.userAgent.match(/Blackberry/i) )
    {
        $('#carriage-promo').addClass("addclass1");
    } else {
        $('#carriage-promo').addClass("addclass2");
        alert('tablet detected');
        //change #carriage-promo to #carriage-promo-2
    }
```

Css class:

```
.addClass1{
       position:'fixed';
       bottom:'0px';
       width:'100%';
}
.addClass2{
      display:'inline-block'; 
      height:'40px';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using jquery try this:

```
$('#carriage-promo-2').addClass('addThisClass');
```

Comment: Of course!! addClass and removeClass, forgot about those entirely.

Much appreciated! :)